# Identify types of circuit(s) that would function as stated

Tags: pulse, output, input, trigger

I am trying to build a circuit that will have a trigger input, a clock input and an output that is (10) pulses at clock frequency for each trigger pulse.

[image]

- Would it be multiple circuits (chips) or just one?
- What circuit/chip name(s) do I search for.
- Any suggested links to explain how to do this?

Comment: What is to happen with a trigger pulse longer than 10 μs? Two successive pulses spaced less than 10 μs?

Comment: It really depends on various other factors, like the maximum input-to-output latency, board size limitation, and so forth. if an inexpensive microcontroller (MCU) covers your needs, I would go that route.

Comment: bteddy, It helps a lot if you write a thorough spec. This should not be hand-waving in a general direction. But a little more precise. For example, is the trigger to occur on the rising or falling edge? What's the range of the width of the trigger? What are its worst-case rise and fall times? Do you want the output clock to start immediately (and with random phase relative to the input clock) when triggered? Or simply pass along the input source regardless of its phase relative to the trigger?

Comment: Thank You [periblepsis] You statements help. Everything is on the rising edge.  Output clock is the same frequency as input clock simply passes along the input source regardless of its phase relative to the trigger.  Thank You

Comment: @bteddy1 That leaves me thinking that so long as the trigger width meets the requirements for detectability, the length doesn't matter. If very long, there won't be a rising edge for a while. Oh, well. So no re-triggering and it's just dead time if it is a long trigger. That leaves me also assuming the rising edge won't be "slow" but instead "fast enough" for whatever circuit is cobbled up, since there's no spec. Given that, you may want [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApjoV.png). (State machine that leads to a schematic.) GATE is what allows CLK through, via AND gate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good start ... Made with [FREE](https://archive.org/details/micro-cap-12-full-cd-version-12.2.0.5) microcap v12, file mc12cd.zip.

You can modify this as you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank You for your time.

Comment: please don't recommend people to download software from your dropbox that could just as well be a virus

Comment: The link Above: "microcap v12, file mc12cd.zip." is 113mb. The Full MC12CD.zip file from the the designer "Spectrum Software" is only 57.6mb. I wouldn't use the above link.

Comment: Link was fixed.